# iOS Core Data - Removing object from relationship causes another relationship to become nil

Tags: ios, core-data

I have app using Core Data where there are multiple Profiles. There are also multiple Categories and Products. Each Category can have multiple Products, and each Product has one Category. Each Profile has a relationship with Products and Categories, as they don't have to show everything. I'm running into a problem were removing a Product from the relationship of the Profile suddenly ends up with it's Category property nil. As this is a required property, it fails the context save.

The Category objects themselves are not being deleted.

Comment: More information would be helpful: Exact definition of the entities and relationships with their delete rules, your code where you remove a Product object, NSLog output showing the results.

Comment: can you post the screenshot of your core data model ?

Comment: if you set your delete rules to be cascade, it happnes to delete the related object. Make sure that you set the delete rule as nullify.